# Keep text with full opacity while fading out the background

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, fade

How do I get get the text to stay at full opacity, while fading the background out?

I need to get a readable text, but have the background fade during mouse `onrollover`. I found solutions like "box" or "text-box", but it didn't work.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // valore iniziale del fade sull'immagine a riposo 
    $(".fade").fadeTo(0, 0.6);

    $(".fade").hover(function () {
        // valore del fade sull'immagine con mouse hover 
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
    },
    function () {
        // ritorno al valore iniziale del fade con mouse out 
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#content > ul > li {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#content > ul > li > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/pages_bg2.png);
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<article id="content"> Text Area </article>
```

Comment: I think everything inside an element with a fade effect is going to be faded no matter what. At least I have never had luck making it work... I would try making them two different absolutely-positioned elements with the text-containing element having a higher z-index. Make them the same size and make onmouseover on the text-containing element cause the background-containing element to fade.

Comment: if you are using css :hover, then just change the element class using onmouseover/onmouseout instead to make the hover effect possible.